# Should we merge tags related to account management?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have several tags that are related to managing accounts.

I propose merging the following tags into [account-management].

- [account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account)
- [account-delete](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-delete)
- [account-transfer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-transfer)
- [account-disabling](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-disabling)
- [accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts)
- [account-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery)

Maybe alternate-account also?

Comment: [account-transfer] may be more closely related with [transfer].

Comment: @Senseful, [transfer] seems like a poorly named tag

Comment: true, so we might want to merge that into these ones as well.

Answer (score 3):

This has now been done.

The following tags:

- [account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account)
- [account-delete](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-delete)
- [account-transfer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-transfer)
- [account-disabling](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-disabling)
- [accounts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounts)
- [account-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery)

have all been merged in to [account-management](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-management)